# Force View's query plan to update?

Tags: postgresql

I have a View whose query plan appears to be cached, is there a way to force the View's plan to be recalculated on each access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out my problem is due to the VIEW containing aggregate functions.

What looks like a cached query plan is really the planner (by design) not pushing a WHERE clause applied outside the VIEW into the VIEW.

Problem explained.